# MS SQL Server Database Option - Transaction Log

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I have a database for staging purpose before move into another main database. It has 5-6 millions records on average. The transaction log keep growing after few days to 30-40 gig. The transaction record not important because I can retrieve from my source again if needed. There are some configuration details needed only.

What's the best way to manage transaction log ?
What database recovery mode should I set - Simple, Full, Bulk Logged ? By default, I selected Full.
Should I just schedule a job to purge the transaction log on a daily basis ?

Any recommendation ? Thanks.

Comment: Reading this : https://www.sqlshack.com/understanding-database-recovery-models/

Answer (score 4):

> The transaction record not important because I can retrieve from my source again if needed.
> . . .
> What database recovery mode should I set

SIMPLE.  Then shrink the log one time.

Comment: @user3015739 The key phrase here is "*one time*". **Shrinking** your log file shouldn't be something you're doing routinely, mostly because it's a heavy operation and if the log is going to **re-grow** anyway due to your normal database usage then **shrinking** was a wasted operation, especially because the **growth** operation is a heavy operation as well, so they're both events that are performance impacting on your database. It's ok to **shrink** in special one-off cases like this when switching **recovery models** as a *start with a clean slate* though.

Answer (score 1):

How much data can you afford to lose in case of a damaged database (i.e., you have to do restore). I.e., what is your RPO? That decides the frequency of your backups.

If only full backup (and possibly also differential) is enough, then set to simple.

If you need more frequent backups, then set to full and do regular log backups.

After above has been settled, shrink the log file to a suitable size.